# Recursion relation and overlapping sub problems

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am new to dynamic programming and I am trying to understand the basics of recursion and memoization while trying to solve the Max sum of non adjacent elements - [Problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-such-that-no-two-elements-are-adjacent/). After reading some theory, one of the basic properties of a recursive function is it should have over lapping sub problems. For the naïve brute force approach to this problem, for my code below, I am having a hard time seeing overlapping problems.

1. Is the reason I am not able to see overlapping sub problems because I don't have a recursive relation?
2. Do I always have to have a recurrence relation in order to have sub problems, i.e., all recursive problems may/may not have sub problems if there is no recurrence relation
3. How can I add memoization if 1 or 2 is holds and I just made a mistake in analysis?

```html
public static int maxSubsetSum(int[] arr) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> cache = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        return maxSumHelper(arr, 0, arr.length , 0, new ArrayList<Integer>(), cache);
    }
    public static int maxSumHelper(int[]arr, int start, int end, int sum, ArrayList<Integer>combo, HashMap<Integer, Integer> cache){
        
        /*
         * if(cache.containsKey(start)) { return; }
         */
        if(start>=end){
            for(int i  = 0; i <combo.size();i++ ) {
                System.out.print(combo.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println();
            return sum;
        }
        for(int i = start; i < arr.length; i++){
            sum+= arr[i];
            combo.add(arr[i]);
            int withMax  = maxSumHelper(arr, i + 2, end, sum, combo, cache);
            sum-=arr[i];
            combo.remove(combo.size() - 1);
            int withoutMax = maxSumHelper(arr, i+ 2, end, sum, combo, cache);
            //cache.put(i, Math.max(withMax, withoutMax));
            max = Math.max(max,Math.max(withMax, withoutMax));
        }
        return max;
    }
```

Comment: `withoutMax = maxSumHelper(arr, i+ 2, end, sum, combo, cache)` looks wrong to me. Shouldn't that be a `+1`?

Comment: no, because for every i, I want the neighbour 1 over and not adjacent

Comment: That's the case where you didn't take `i` though.

Comment: @DavidEisentat, you are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> one of the basic properties of a recursive function is it should have over lapping sub problems

This is a condition for getting a benefit from dynamic programming, but is not a condition for a recursive function in general.

> I am having a hard time seeing overlapping problems.

They are there. But first a correction: the second recursive call should pass `i+1` as argument, not `i+2`. This is because it deals with the case where you *do not* include the value at `i` for the sum, and so it is allowed to include the value at `i+1`.

Now take this example input, and looking for a sum that is maximised:

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1 }
                 ^
                 i=5
```

Let's focus on the call that gets as argument `start=5`: the most we can *add* to the current sum is 3 + 1 = 4. This fact is independent on what the value is of the `sum` argument, and so we could benefit from a cache that would tell us what the maximised *additional* value is at a given index `start`.

There are many paths that lead to this call with `start=5`. The path (`combo`) could include any of these values from the input *before* index 5:

- 1, 3, 0
- 1, 2
- 2, 2
- 2, 0
- 3, 0
- 2
- 0
- nothing

So if the first case drills down to the end and determines that for index 5 the greatest additional value is 4 (3+1), there is no need to do this search again for the other cases, and you can just do `return sum + cache.get(start)`.

### Side note

It is better practice to let the recursive function return that "additional" sum, and *not* pass it the sum-so-far as argument. Just add the value of the current selection (if any) to the greatest of the sums that come back from recursive calls and return *that*. This way it is also clearer how you can use memoization.

Comment: Thank you for putting me on the right path yet again with a great detailed explanation.

Comment: I am struggling a bit with the note....though I think what you are saying is for a particular index calculate the max additional sum it can offer. However, how do I keep track of the total sum without passing in the sum as a parameter. Any further clarification is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The sum grows out of recursion, bottom up. You get two sums from the two recursive calls, keep the greatest of those two, add `arr[i]` to it, and return that to your own caller.

Comment: ...ahhh i see that which is why passing in the current sum in my function leads to wrong values being cached and hence I simply cannot cache Math.max(withMax, withoutMax) for index i as it contains the total sum and not just the additional...hmmmmm.....